# Uninitialized mutex goes out of scope -- cleanup?

Tags: c++, multithreading, initialization, pthreads, mutex

I am trying to clean up someone else's code and I see a lot of cases where a class contains a `pthread_mutex_t` member variable. In a number of cases, `pthread_mutex_init()` is never called, nor is lock/unlock. When that object goes out of scope, what, if anything, needs to be done to properly clean up after it? Can I try to unlock it (if it hasn't been init'd, what happens)? Do I need to destroy it?

The analysis tool is saying that the resource may be lost. Has anything been lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing a cleanup and you find a mutex which is never used, you should consider removing it.

If the mutex is used, you should call [`pthread_mutex_destroy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_destroy). Class destructor is a good place to do it, especially if [`pthread_mutex_init()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init) is called in the constructor.

Note that the mutex must be unlocked by the time it is destroyed or undefined behavior will result. This should be ensured by the way mutex is used however.

Comment: I should have said: there are cases where it is not used.  It frequently is, but not always.  _init() is not called unless it is used -- and I can't be certain.  Can I call 'destroy' on a mutex if it has NOT been _init()'ed?

Comment: I recommend against destroying an uninitialized mutex. Add a call to `pthread_mutex_init()` as well as to `pthread_mutex_destroy()`.

Comment: Note however that `pthread_mutex_init ()` isn't the only ways to initialize a mutex. You can also initialize them with `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`. See the manpage linked from the question for details.

Comment: @AdamZalcman but when you initialize a lot of things and fail in the middle it's handy to be able to `pthread_mutex_destroy()` everything regardless of it being actually initialized or not. The `free(NULL)` is a thing for this reason.